# How to read a cell from matrix in a file

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a huge matrix that I saved with `savetxt` with `numpy` library. 
Now I want to read a single cell from that matrix e.g

```
cell = getCell(i,j)
print cell 

>> return the value : 10 for example
```

I tried this :

```
x = np.loadtxt("fname.m",dtype="int",usecols=([i]))
cell=x[j]
```

but it is really slow because I loop over many index. Is there a way to do that without reading useless lines ?

Comment: you can do something like `x = np.loadtxt(..., skiprows=i)[0][j]`

Comment: Thanks @SaulloCastro for the reply. I don't think that your answer is the solution because it still read all the rows after `i` and then it takes the `j` column. What I'm looking for is something that allows me to read the `i,j` directly without reading the line or the column.

Comment: to get really efficient you can try something with `file.seek()`, but this will get (much) more complicated...

Comment: Text files are not meant for random access.  If you need to repeatedly access select lines (that's what you mean by 'cell'?), choose some other file format or database.

Comment: @TantaouiElMehdi did you check the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

One way to go is to exhaust a `file` iterator until the line you want:

```
with open('fname.m') as f:
    for _ in range(i):
         line = f.next()
    cell = line.split()[j]
```